# rails app gives error "can not load translations from {ru.yml path} expected it to return a hash, but does not"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, centos, yaml, centos6

My application works fine locally, but when i'm installing it to production server, i get the following error running `rails server` and requesting page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can not load translations from {app}/config/locales/ru.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not).
```

I have YAML translation ru.yml:

```
ru:
  clients:
    index: 
      title: Список клиентов
```

And error happens while calling, ex:

```
%h1=t '.title'
```

My development machine is running Mac OS X ML

Production server is CentOS 6 with rvm and libyaml installed.

Both servers are on Ruby 1.9.2p320 and Rails 3.2.8

Comment: What does it do when you read it by hand in rails console? `YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/ru.yml'))`

Comment: It gives me error on following string:
     `default: %d.%m.%Y %H:%M`

Comment: There was a problem in this line. I added quotes: `default: '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'` and got a hash. Problem solved, thank you!

Comment: Nice, than it can be closed. :)

Comment: @lich please post your own answer (see below) so this question is closed, then it doesn't show up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operation `YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/ru.yml'))` gave me error in one of lines.

I added quotes: `default: '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'` and got a hash. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about using `psych` YAML engine which can not parse strings with % sign and generates SyntaxError exception.

Use `syck` engine instead. Add the following code to the end of your `config/boot.rb` file

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

hint: syck requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.